# MSBuild community tasks can not be loaded even when it is installed

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild-task

I had a WPF application that I did not touch for around a year and now I have a new PC.
When I clone the application from git and tried to run it, I am getting this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.AssemblyInfo" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\MyData\SourceCodes\Library\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

When I try to install Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core from here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core/

I am getting this error:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 15.9.20'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core -Version 15.9.20
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

How can I fix this problem?

I am using VS 2017, but the original project was compiled using VS 2013, is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install .Net Framework 3.5 ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)), because you need 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities, Version=2.0.0.0'. It is one of the dependencies that was crashed swithich to version 4.0 if I correctly remember